# Shell script and mv directory creates extra character but not when run on cmd line

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I need to rename a directory in a crontab job so created bash file to run the script that that will move the folder prior to running mongodump command.
When I run the command directory on the command line the directory is moved and renamed without any extra characters

When I run the move.sh that directory is moved but with an trailing `?` at the end of the directory name.  `Rm -R /change071105^M`  also appear.. 
Any insight is appreciated

Checked move.sh for extra character.

Directory was renamed and all files appeared.

Created a move.sh  with:

Resume of `mv` in script renames directory as:
`change071105?`  not the expected `change071115`

Ran command at the command line to confirm

```
mv /mongo_backup/change /mongo_backup/change$(date --date='1 day ago' +'%m%d%y')
```

also checked move.sh for extra spaces ..

```
 #!/bin/bash
    dd=$(date --date='1 day ago' +'%m%d%y')
    mv -v "/mongo_backup/change" "/mongo_backup/change$dd"
    #mv /mongo_backup/change /mongo_backup/change$(date --date='1 day ago' +'%m%d%y')
```

Comment: in bash file:  mv -v   space added

Comment: Does your script file have Windows line endings but you're not running it on Windows?

Comment: Also please read up on how to properly format code in stackoverflow flavor markdown and edit your question so it's legible.

Comment: Run `bash -x yourscript` to run it with logging of exactly what it executes. If you have DOS newlines, they'll show up as `$'...\r'`

Comment: BTW, this is literally item #1 in the "before asking about problematic code" section of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info

Comment: you should perform dos2unix.  ^M this refers to the line ending from windows file copied to unix environment

Answer (score 0):

Issue was created in notepad on a windows machine and extra characters when creating scripts:   added mv -v and when running script  >sh    the \r appeared in output

Refined search and below fixed this issue
sed -i 's/\r$//' scriptname.sh